# Spring Maven RESTful app not working

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven

I followed a number of blogs/articles for Spring+Maven+RESTful service example, and followed this one - http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-rest-web-service-json-example-tomcat

I created my project from scratch by following the steps in the example, but my restful service is not returning response. Here are the pieces of code which I think could be missing something :

```
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping("/data")
  public class PersonController {

  @RequestMapping("/person")
  public String getPersonDetail(@RequestParam(value = "id",required = false,
                                                    defaultValue = "0") Integer id) {
    return "Hello " + id;
}
```

Here is the WebAppInitializer

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {  
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
    ctx.register(AppConfig.class);  
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);    
    Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));  
    dynamic.addMapping("/");  
    dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);  
}  
}
```

I also tried changing to spring instead of spring boot, here is my current pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.concretepage</groupId>
<artifactId>Spring4</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I learned that if I am using annotations, I do not need to specify additional mappings in web.xml. Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">

<display-name>JAX RS Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

And, lastly I tried accessing this service using `http://localhost:8080/Spring4/data/person?id=5`

but it simply returns "Not Found". When I access `http://localhost:8080/Spring4/`, it returns "Forbidden", so the app definitely gets deployed.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: I have tried deploying on tomcat 8 as well as wildfly 8. Both give the same result.

Comment: Annotation-based servlet configuration isn't available in 2.4.

Comment: @chrylis - I tried changing it to 3.1, but eclipse is marking it red. So which version works ?

Comment: Minimum version for annotation-based servlet configuration is 3.0 I believe. Does `@RequestMapping(value="/person", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain")` help?

Comment: @Raj Change the version attribute of the web-app element in web.xml to *3.1*.

Comment: Too many moving parts, Do you want to clone my example and try. Good luck https://github.com/kamoor/spring-boot-sample

Comment: @kamoor - I am getting connection refused when running this. The port 8080 is free (verified with telnet). See exception - http://pastebin.com/tDSfUQih

Answer (score 0):

I guess most of the tutotials are just outdated or missing the details.

I solved this by creating the project in different way. In eclipse, I went to new project wizard and selected spring starter project. Then I brought in my code (I did not need to modify the pom.xml)

From that point onward, my RESTful app started working.

Answer (score -1):

You should add the annotation `@ResponseBody` which indicates a method return value should be bound to the web response body. ([ResponseBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html))

```
@RequestMapping("/person")
public @ResponseBody String getPersonDetail(@RequestParam(value = "id",required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer id) {
    return "Hello " + id;
}
```

**EDIT** : `@RestController` is already annotated with `@ResponseBody`

But if you don't have a dispatcher-servlet, you should have one.

In your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="YOUR CONTROLLER PACKAGE" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>PATH TO YOUR JSPs</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: tried this and re-deployed, still no change in response

Comment: after adding dispatcher-servlet I am getting 404 - Not Found

Comment: op already defines a DispatcherServlet using WebApplicationInitializer.